# Creating custom CRS by rotating EPSG:27700 OSGB (for mine grid)?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj, qgis-customization

I am trying to georeference a mine plan, but it uses a custom CRS based on the following:

[image]

I gather I just need to rotate the OSGB grid system by 25 17'59" ?

is this just a case of modifying the default OSBG WKT somehow?

heres what a rough layer looks like ( bold line OSGB 50m grid )

[image]

Comment: Or georefernce to the OS grid lines the orange ones?

Comment: The faint ones are the mine grid from the image, the bold ones are just ones I have turned on in qgis to show the rotation required.